# Como obter um valor procurado em uma string em PHP?

Tags: php, html

Tenho um string que contem codigo html :

```
$pagina = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang='pt-BR'>
<title>Pagina</title>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<div class='conteudo'>
    <div class='valor'>
    1000
    </div>
</div>
</html>
";

$valor = $pagina //pegar na variável $pagina o que esta entre  <div class='valor'> e </div>
```

Existe alguma função em PHP que pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

```
$pagina = "<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html  lang='pt-BR'>
   <title>Pagina</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <div class='conteudo'>
     <div class='valor'>
     1000
     </div>
    </div>
  </html>
";
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($pagina);

$elements = $doc->getElementById("valor");

echo $elements[0]->nodeValue;
```

Para mais informações: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo ajudou demais, eu procurei e não tinha achado de jeito nenhum.